# Youtube Interesting Method of page LOAD

Tags: javascript, html, video, youtube

First sorry for my bad english. I"ll try to make the question understandable.This is only for educational porpuse :)

When you watch a video in youtube and change to another video in the related ones. There is a lot of parts of the page don"t change. So if you change the local file (the page what is downloaded to your pc when the server sent it to you) you can see the modifications is still here. So if you delete de youtube logo and acces another video (by clicking the related ones) you see the video,title,description and related videos change but no the header. You can see in the developer console (in opera for example) and you can check it. When we click a new related video it don"t load a new page. Lets explain the image

[image]

1: You select one icon of the header

2: You delete the code from it

3: Click in another video and the header is still with the modification

My observations: It could be a ajax reload method, but (what i know) you can"t change the url of the browser bar (for security reasons). So how youtube achieve this ?

PD: Maybe there is a new technology and this is incredible common. But i like to know how this can be made :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty typical for a Single Page Application (SPA). Using the HTML5 History API, the page script intercepts changes the the URL (as long as they're within the same domain) and uses a View Router to re-render the page with the new details, including making requests for new data.

So when you start on one video and navigate to another, the browser doesn't actually "navigate" for real - as you say, it takes the new video ID from the URL, loads the metadata for the video from some back-end service and renders the appropriate page.

YouTube appears to be built using some version of AngularJS (which makes sense, as Google wrote the Angular framework) so if you want to know more you can read up on how to build Angular apps, but most modern web applications are built on a similar foundation. It's generally a good idea because reloading an entire page is expensive and slow compared to just updating the bits that need to change.